# How to read multiple data with changing NA patterns?

Tags: r, na, missing-data, read.table

I try to read in some measurement data with the following code

```
UGT2008 <- rbind.fill(lapply(filelist[1:70], fread, header = F, dec = ".", sep = "\t", na.strings = c("NA","%-","%"), skip = 1L,stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

I use this code, becasue I have multiple data, I want to bind together to one big dataset.
The problem is, wrong values, which should be treated as NA, are marked by "%" at the beginning of the value. So, NA is not one single characters, but a sample of different numbers starting with "%".
The number of different wrong values is to large to name all of the them as "na.strings".
After reading the data, all columns are character, but should be numeric.

The data look like this.

```
Datum   Zeit    Temp1/grad  Temp2/grad  Pyrr+/W/qm  Pyrr-/W/qm  Global/W/qm H-Flux/W/qm Windr./grad Pegel/cmWS  Phar/µmol   Bspg./V Widerst./kOhm   Blattb./j/n 
18.12.00    09:55      2.64  -98.14  -42.34   47.23   68.14    7.44  341.08    0.15  151.76   11.08 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    09:56      2.63  -98.13  -19.07   47.04   65.36    7.31  346.73    0.02  151.28   11.06 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    09:57      2.62  -98.14  -43.73   44.92   64.32    7.36  353.86   -0.01  147.53   11.07 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    09:58      2.75  -98.18  -43.83   44.21   63.42    7.40  360.33    0.12  143.96   11.10 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    09:59      2.65  -98.12  -43.53   43.60   63.42    7.40  356.76    0.12  144.44   11.08 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:00      2.74  -98.18  -43.70   43.67   63.42    7.40  359.96    0.13  144.73   11.10 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:01      2.62  -98.14  -44.24   42.90   61.00    7.57    3.66    0.14  139.34   11.16 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:02      2.62  -98.12  -44.34   40.52   58.08    7.06  356.71    0.00  136.45   11.08 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:03      2.74  -98.18  -46.03   41.04   59.19    7.53  360.35    0.14  135.87   11.12 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:04      2.63  -98.12  -44.64   42.35   60.86    7.31  347.55    0.13  140.11   11.12 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:05      2.62  -98.13  -20.39   43.54   60.37    7.14  361.00   -0.02  144.35   11.09 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:06      2.72  -98.18  -45.32   41.20   58.92    7.36  353.24    0.13  135.77   11.13 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:07      2.73  -98.18  -45.56   40.91   57.88    7.36  356.10    0.10  134.04   11.13 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:08      2.62  -98.12  -43.05   41.94   58.85    7.01    6.54    0.01  140.11   11.14 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:09      2.63  -98.14  -43.90   43.06   60.72    7.23  338.23   -0.01  144.25   11.10 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:10      2.62  -98.13  -43.86   43.48   61.27    7.23  356.67   -0.01  145.12   11.10 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:11      2.63  -98.13  -44.13   42.74   59.26    7.19  360.77   -0.01  141.07   11.11 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:12      2.62  -98.12  -45.18   41.39   58.43    7.36  360.31    0.13  136.06   11.15 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:13      2.61  -98.18  -31.82   40.72   58.08    7.36    0.85    0.00  140.20   11.14 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:14      2.63  -98.13  -44.88   41.42   59.12    7.53    6.60    0.09  139.53   11.20 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:15      2.62  -98.11  -43.29   41.71   59.82    7.10   10.82    0.00  143.77   11.16 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:16      2.62  -98.12  -43.05   43.99   64.32    7.31    7.32    0.12  151.09   11.20 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:17      2.74  -98.18  -40.82   48.32   71.39    7.36  156.24    0.11  166.50   11.19 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:18      2.61  -98.18  -38.28   52.98   74.17    7.06  188.01    0.01  178.16   11.16 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:19      2.62  -98.13  -37.61   53.94   76.94    7.44  142.70    0.12  179.41   11.22 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:20      2.63  -98.12  -37.40   53.49   76.04    7.40  305.02    0.11  179.51   11.21 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:21      2.63  -98.14  -38.52   52.27   73.89    7.31  312.70   -0.01  179.61   11.20 %-2546.78      1.00 
18.12.00    10:22      2.63  -98.13  -14.97   52.82   71.60    7.06  280.18   -0.01  176.72   11.20 %-2546.78      1.00
```

I tried

```
na.strings = c("NA",grepl("^","%"))
```

but that`s not working.

```
na.strings = c("NA",patter=("%*"))
```

is also not working.

Do you have any idea, how to set changing patterns of na.strings or to identify "%" as the start of an NA-Value?

Cheers,
Florian

Comment: Not sure I understand. You speak of `NA` but there aren't any `NA` values. You also mention `%`, which occurs at string start in column `Pegel/cmWS`. What exactly do you want to achieve--remove `%` or something else?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your question. I want to turn all values which starts with `%` into `NA` values. So, the columns should be numeric at hte end and not character.

Comment: Do you have these values only in one column or in more than one?

Comment: more than one. In nearly every column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c("%123", "123", "5.5"),
  v2 = c("45.00006", "%-12.8899", "%900.77"),
  v3 = c("55", "66", "%432.002")
)
```

Solution:

Use `as.numeric` and `lapply` to accomplish both goals, that of turning the `%`-headed values into `NA` and that of converting the columns in the dataframe to numeric type:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.numeric)
        v1       v2 v3
[1,]    NA 45.00006 55
[2,] 123.0       NA 66
[3,]   5.5       NA NA
```

Comment: Please see edited answer. Does this address your issue?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! It works very well. I thought it will be easier to erase the problem during reading the data, but this is a very smooth solution.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer.